# Kohana: trying to dynamically change content (not the whole page)

Tags: variables, dynamic, kohana, bind

I am struggling to get my head around this since too many hours and I need some help.:)
I have a website build on Kohana and want to dynamically change the content of some text when the user click one button or and another. Not sure if I am doing it the right way but this what I did so far (ho by the way I am new to this framework).

Controller:

class Controller_Homepage extends Controller_General {

```
   public $template = "template/widepage";

   public $textbuyer = array (
        'text1' => "homepage.buyer.bigtext1", //transfering language variable.
        'text2' => "homepage.buyer.bigtext2",
        //with more ...
       );   

   public $textseller = array (
        'text1' => "homepage.seller.bigtext1",
        'text2' => "homepage.seller.bigtext2",
        'text3' => "homepage.seller.bigtext3",
        //with more ...
       );   
    public $thetext = array ("textbuyer"); //the defaul array is textbuyer
```

public function action_index() {

```
        $this->content = View::factory("homepage") 
            ->bind('pagetext', $thetext );


        if ($this->request->method() === Request::POST) {
            $post= $this->request->post();
            if (isset($post['buyer'])){
                $thetext = $textbuyer;//gives rrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: textbuyer
            //    arr::overwrite($thetext, $textbuyer);
            }else if(isset($post['seller'])){
                $thetext = $textseller;
                }
        }

}
```

Section of my view to show how I use the variable in the view:

```
        <div class="container_content">
            <div>
                <p id='sline'><?php echo $pagetext['text1']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div>
```

Can't get the content of my array to the view and when I click on one of the two buttons this code gives me the following error: ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: textbuyer. What I am doing wrong ? Why I get the error I mentionned ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you define the variables like this

```
public $textbuyer = ...
public $textseller = ...
public $thetext = ...
```

They are attributes of your class. And since they are, you need to call them via

```
$this->textbuyer
$this->textseller
$this->thetext
```

Just as you call methods inside the same class with `$this->methodName()` instead of `methodName()`.

```
class Foo {
    public $bar = "hello ";
    public function foo() {
        $bar = "world";
        print $this->bar.$bar; // hello world
    }
}
```

This would work just fine and you get the error because you never define `$textbuyer` (because you want to call `$this->textbuyer`).

Comment: Thank you kingkero, will try this and let you know the results. Would this change when its a private variable instead of a public one ? I mean do I have to call them teh same way ? Thanks!

Comment: No, this would not change